# Using @ngrx/Effect an effect is not being triggered by an Action

Tags: angular7

I expect that the Effect that I created should be triggered by dispatching an action, but it is not happening.
The action is being dispatched correctly, but the effect seems that is not properly watching this.
I created this effect:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { PoliciesService } from 'app/services/policies';
import * as policiesActions from '../actions/policies.actions';
import { Policy } from 'app/dtos/policy.dto';
import { PoliciesMapper } from 'app/services/policies/policies.mapper';

Injectable();
export class PoliciesEffect {

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private policyService: PoliciesService
    ) { }
    @Effect()
    getPolicies$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<policiesActions.GetPoliciesAction>(
            policiesActions.ActionPoliciesType.GET_POLICIES
        ),
        mergeMap((actions: policiesActions.GetPoliciesAction) =>
            this.policyService.getPolicies().pipe(
                map((policies: Policy[]) =>
                    new policiesActions.GetPoliciesActionSuccess(PoliciesMapper.policiesCollectionToPoliciesModelCollection(policies))
                ),
                catchError(err => of(new policiesActions.GetPoliciesActionFailed(err)))
            )
        )
    );
}
```

This effect expect to be triggered once the Action GetPoliciesAction is being dispatch. 
This is not happening so I am not able to do the HTTP request to get my data from the server.

Here are the Actions that I created using @ngrx/store:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Policy } from 'app/dtos/policy.dto';
import { PolicyModel } from 'app/models/policy.model';

export enum ActionPoliciesType {
    GET_POLICIES = '[Policies] Get all policies list',
    GET_POLICIES_SUCCESS = '[Policies] Policies received succesfully',
    GET_POLICIES_FAILED = '[Policies] Policies reception failed'
}

export class GetPoliciesAction implements Action {
    readonly type = ActionPoliciesType.GET_POLICIES;
    constructor() { }
}
export class GetPoliciesActionSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = ActionPoliciesType.GET_POLICIES_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: PolicyModel[]) { }
}
export class GetPoliciesActionFailed implements Action {
    readonly type = ActionPoliciesType.GET_POLICIES_FAILED;
    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}
export type PoliciesActions =
    GetPoliciesAction |
    GetPoliciesActionSuccess |
    GetPoliciesActionFailed;
```

And here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { IPoliciesService } from './services/policies/policies.interface';
import { PoliciesService } from './services/policies';
import { reducers } from './redux/reducers/reducers';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { EffectsModule, Actions} from '@ngrx/effects';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: IPoliciesService,
    useClass: PoliciesService
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing your effects class to the effects module. In your ngModule import for EffectsModule you are passing an empty array. Your PoliciesEffects service should be in that array.

Comment: It worked ! What to do if I have more than one effect service? Should just pass all the effect services pushed in this array ?

Comment: Yes, all effects you need to register in this module must be included in the array